# Displays the contents of php in RichTextBox

Tags: php, richtextbox

Tell me how I can bring this line

```
   Properties.Settings.Default.api_url + "?skey=" + Properties.Settings.Default.skey_api + "&news";
```

in RichTextBox?

This line is the site address and file that reads the information from the database and outputs the text that I want to display in the RichTextBox

Comment: Whata are you trying ??

Comment: I try to display the text of the php in richtextbox